# Ingesting/importing a country specific Google Mobility CSV file into Python

Tags: python, csv, data-ingestion

Hi Stackoverflow Community,

I am trying to import ONLY Australia's google mobility csv file into Python from: https://www.gstatic.com/covid19/mobility/Region_Mobility_Report_CSVs.zip (which is available at: https://www.google.com/covid19/mobility/).. However, google now provides a folder of all csv files.

I am wondering if someone can point me into the right direction of how to import a file within a zipped folder online.

I would like to achieve this 'without downloading' the zip folder into my PC and then importing AUS csv. Wondering if there is a way to do all this using a code so everytime I run a code, python grabs the latest AUS csv file from the URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do 3 things in sequence:

1. download the zip file
2. read the zip file
3. read Australia's csv (assuming you know its filename)

We can do all this just with python's built-in modules!

First, download the file with `urllib.request`:

```py
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.gstatic.com/covid19/mobility/Region_Mobility_Report_CSVs.zip") as f:
    zip_data: bytes = f.read()
```

Second, read the archive. [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) can help you with that.

```py
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

z = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(zip_data))
```

In this step, we wrapped `zip_data` (bytes) in `BytesIO` (a file-like object) because `zipfile.ZipFile` takes ["a path to a file (a string), a file-like object or a path-like object"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile).

Last, parse the csv file with [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

```py
from io import StringIO

with z.open("2020_AU_Region_Mobility_Report.csv") as au_csv:
    australia_data = csv.reader(StringIO(au_csv.read().decode("utf8")))

for row in australia_data:
    print(row)
```

The line where we parse the csv is a little convoluted because `csv.reader` takes an iterator of strings, but `au_csv.read()` returns one blob of bytes. So we have to decode those bytes, *then* turn it into something the reader accepts.

Combine all of the above:

```py
import csv
import urllib.request
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO, StringIO

# Download
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.gstatic.com/covid19/mobility/Region_Mobility_Report_CSVs.zip") as f:
    zip_data: bytes = f.read()

# Open zip file and parse csv
with zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(zip_data)) as z:
    with z.open("2020_AU_Region_Mobility_Report.csv") as au_csv:
        australia_data = csv.reader(StringIO(au_csv.read().decode("utf8")))

for row in australia_data:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, this looks like I will have to download "Region_Mobility_Report_CSVs.zip" into my PC while I was looking to access the folder, get the csv file without downloading the zip folder.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to download the file one way or another. When you asked "how to import a file within a zipped folder online.", did you mean to ask how to get python to download the zip file for you?

Comment: Yup. Sorry should have written carefully, I want to read content of AU CSV file into my Python using the code. Without having to download zip folder or anything.

Comment: Answer updated, hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Eric, always something new to learn! :)

Comment: Good luck and have fun :)